# CSS - Spacing issue between Text and dropdown

Tags: html, css, angular, forms, flexbox

I need to reduce the space between the text "Allow type of Compartment Option" and the dropdown box.

Code used:

```css
.cl-checkbox {
      padding-left: 20px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      padding-top: 20px;
         }
    
    .cl-checkbox label {
      padding-left: 25px;
      text-indent: -25px;
      padding-top: 3px;
       }
    
    .cl-checkbox input {
      vertical-align: bottom;
      top: -1px;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 10px 2px 0 0;
       }
     .form-control {
    background: #d8d8e5;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #56565c;
}
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(1.5em + .75rem + 2px);
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}
.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
   .form-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -5px;
    margin-left: -5px;
}
    
.form-row>.col, .form-row>[class*=col-] {
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
```

```html
<div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group  cl-checkbox">
              <label for="isRequired"><input class="form-check-input position-static" type="checkbox"
                  value="option1" id="value12" ">Allow type of Compartment Option</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="cl-label">Type </label>
              <select class="form-control" formControlName="type_XID">
                <option>Select Type</option>
              </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

When this code is used, the output can be seen here:

[image: Image 1]

When the page is minimized, the output can be seen here:

[image: Image 2]

All css classes are global classes and is used throughout the project.
New css class can be introduced to resolve this issue.
Kindly mention ways to reduce the space between the text and drop down without overlapping on text when page is minimized.(Reduce the gap marked in orange in the image):

[image: Image 3]

Image 4 - Overlapping on text should not occur when page is minimized.

[image: Image 4]

@Warden330 Space issue is resolved but the row has moved right after using your code Image 5- [Image 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHikK.png)

Comment: which UI framework is used here? Where `form-row` is declared?

Comment: @IsraGab I have used Angular. Also added code for other CSS classes also.

Comment: I asked about UI framework. Are you using @angular/material?

Comment: @IsraGab good point. I was about to answer with CSS Flexbox but if the form-row is from any framework id rather not mess around with custom CSS

Comment: @IsraGab Sorry, not familiar with the framework

Comment: @ClarkeGriffin did you forget to add the "form-row" class to your CSS in the snippet you provided?

Comment: AFAIK form `form-row`, `form-control` are global CSS comes from angular/material framework

Comment: @Warden330 Yes, I have added now.

Comment: Following the css you provided, the  select should go below the checkbox and not overlap it

Comment: @IsraGab Firstly, need to reduce the space between text and dropdown. Next, when the page is minimized, it should not overlap.

Comment: ah wait, you want them to be right next to each other but never overlap?

Comment: @Warden330 Yes , it should not overlap with the text when the page is minimized.

Comment: Alright, edited my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add further Rules to the form-row class to ensure that there is always space.
Edit: I also added a new class to the first Element in the row so you can specify its behaviour. The row now centers all Elements so they are in the middle of the screen. The Code is commented where i made changes.

```css
.cl-checkbox {
      padding-left: 20px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      padding-top: 20px;
         }
    
    .cl-checkbox label {
      padding-left: 25px;
      text-indent: -25px;
      padding-top: 3px;
       }
    
    .cl-checkbox input {
      vertical-align: bottom;
      top: -1px;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 10px 2px 0 0;
       }
     .form-control {
    background: #d8d8e5;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #56565c;
}
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(1.5em + .75rem + 2px);
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}
.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.form-row {
    display: flex;
    /*Shorthand for flex-direction + flex-wrap*/
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    /*horizontal positioning of elements*/
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin-right: -5px;
    margin-left: -5px;
}
/*new class to give the first Element in your form-row some behaviour*/
.row-checkbox{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  /*make it move all the way to the right*/
  justify-content: flex-end;
  /*You can set how much space you want between the Checkbox-Text and the dropdown here with the padding*/
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.form-row>.col, .form-row>[class*=col-] {
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
/*You didnt close the tag here*/   
 }
```

```html
<div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group  cl-checkbox row-checkbox">
          <label for="isRequired"><input class="form-check-input position-static" type="checkbox"
              value="option1" id="value12">Allow type of Compartment Option</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row-dropdown">
          <label class="cl-label">Type </label>
          <select class="form-control" formControlName="type_XID">
            <option>Select Type</option>
          </select>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group  cl-checkbox row-checkbox">
      <label for="isRequired"><input class="form-check-input position-static" type="checkbox"
          value="option1" id="value12">A different Checkbox</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group  cl-checkbox row-checkbox">
      <label for="isRequired"><input class="form-check-input position-static" type="checkbox"
          value="option1" id="value12">Anotherdifferent Checkbox</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Space issue is resolved but the entire row has moved to the right. I have added output after your code as Image 5 in original post. Please check.

Comment: uhm.. so you added an additional row, has it the same CSS as the ones i edited? because the entire row is not moving to the right, just the first element inside of the row is moved to the right (justify-content: flex-end).

Comment: Yes, it has the same css. I dont want to move it the first element to the right.It should be in the left itself and the drop down should be next to it.

Comment: Okay i edited again. This time i changed justify-content to space-start for the form-row class. As you can see it all moves to the left now and all Checkboxes are on one level. Is that better or do you mean you want it to be centered but all checkboxes aligned?

Comment: @ClarkeGriffin glad i could help, please accept the answer so the question doesnt stay open